# Electric displacement vector $\mathbf{D}$: linear dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, conductors, dielectric

Excuse me for this simple question, but I have occurred of a clarity for this question. The Electric displacement vector $\mathbf{D}$ is defined, as:

$$\mathbf{D}=\epsilon  \mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$$
where $\mathbf{E}$ is electric field and $\mathbf{P}$ the vector polarization density. Polarization is typical of electrification of the insulators. The dielectric term is equivalent to insulation. Why when $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{0}\iff \mathbf{D}=\epsilon  \mathbf{E}$, we say *ideal dielectrics*?

Shouldn't we say *ideal conductors*?

Comment: I am not familiar with this definition of an ideal dielectric. I am familiar with considering lossless dielectrics ideal, rather than when the polarization density is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first formula is not entirely correct. The correct one is
$$\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P,$$
i.e. the $\epsilon_0$ in the equation is *always the vacuum permittivity*, regardless of whether it's in a dielectric or not (e.g. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field)). Now for a simple (linear, isotropic and homogeneous) dielectric, the polarization density $\mathbf P$ is typically proportional to the electric field:
$$\mathbf P = \epsilon_0\chi \mathbf E,$$
with the (dimensionless) proportionality constant $\chi$ being the [electric susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility).

Substituting the second equation into the first one gives
$$\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 (1+\chi) \mathbf E,$$
or defining $\epsilon_r \equiv 1+\chi$ as the *relative permittivity* or dielectric constant, this results in the familiar equation
$$\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \mathbf E = \epsilon \mathbf E.$$

Also note that $\mathbf P \neq 0$ in this case, as it should for an insulator.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. But when I write $\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \mathbf E = \epsilon \mathbf E$, why $\mathbf P \neq 0$?

Comment: @Sebastiano Because from the second equation in my answer $\mathbf P = \epsilon_0 \chi \mathbf E = \epsilon_0 (\epsilon_r-1) \mathbf E$. So since $\mathbf E \neq 0$, you also have $\mathbf P \neq 0$.